# AC current flow

Tags: ac, generator

In an AC system the voltage is generated via large scale alternators-

in a DC battery 'electrical energy is stored' due to the galvanic cell and thus electron flow only occurs between the two points of that particular battery.

-In AC what is causing that flow of electrons or i.e what is the 'negative' terminal of an AC system?

Comment: The motion of the machine causes coils of conductive wire to move in the presence of  magnetic field. This motion induces an electric field in the wire. The electric field is carried through the wires to various locations where power is needed.

Comment: In case you were wondering, either terminal of an AC generator can be connected to earth (sometimes neither). This is not for some electron flow reason, it's done because a) it saves one wire from the power station (i.e. money saving) and b) so that in your house only one out of the two AC leads will have and serious voltage on it (i.e. a safety feature). In most households, the neutral is tied to the earth in and *only* in the fusebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternator has two output terminals - the AC voltage is developed between those terminals, by the action of magnetic fields in the alternator on coils connected to the output terminals.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Peter! So is one terminal used as the 'live' and the other terminal connected to the earth?

Comment: One output terminal of an alternator may be connected to the earth, but it doesn't need to be.  For current to flow, you need a complete circuit from one terminal of the alternator, through the load, and back to the other terminal of the alternator.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So what is going on with the 'potentials' or rather what I was taught that because the earth you stand on is at zero volt and if you touch the live wire in a socket you would get shocked because of the difference in potential, or is it that you are completing the circuit back to the other terminal at the alternator?

Comment: In the AC power distribution system, the Neutral wire is connected to Earth/Ground.  If you touch the "Live" wire while also touching a grounded object, you will get a shock because you are completing a circuit from one terminal of the alternator to the other, and you will experience a potential difference across your body.

Comment: Right I've gotcha, so what would happen If the neutral wasn't connected to earth but rather a direct connection back to the alternator and you touched the 'live' wire and then ground?

Answer (score 0):

Large rotating magnetic fields in generators create the alternating voltage from the flux reversals coupled between rotor and stator. This ElectroMotive Force (EMF) creates the voltage. Current depends on the load. Each output alternates in a sine motion according to the rotation of the generator rotor and stator windings where the number of poles determines the number of cycles per revolution. The voltage can be regulated by some means such as field current.